# how to add another row in one array?

Tags: php, android, arrays

I am getting the array of invitations and for each invitation's row by sender_id from invitation row I am retrieving user's detail from users table.

I want to add user's detail in the same invitations array. I tried to add like this.

```
    function getInvitations()
{
    $database = new Database(ContactsConstants::DBHOST,ContactsConstants::DBUSER,ContactsConstants::DBPASS,ContactsConstants::DBNAME);
    $dbConnection = $database->getDB();

    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Invitation` WHERE Invitation.invitee_no = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($this-> invitee_no));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $invitations = array();

    if (count($rows) > 0) {

        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("Select * from Users where user_id =?");
            $stmt->execute(array($row['sender_id']));

            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $invitations[] = $row;
            $invitations[] = $result;
        }

        $response = array("status" => 1, "message" => "Success", "Invitations" => $invitations);
        return json_encode($response);
    }

    else {
        $response = array("status"=>-1,"message"=>"Invitations list is empty");
        return json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

output I am getting like this:

```
    {
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Success",
  "Invitations": [
    {
      "invitation_id": "369",
      "date": "12/08/2016",
      "invitee_no": "8655864341",
      "status": "1",
      "sender_id": "44"
    },
    {
      "user_id": "44",
      "user_name": "Angel",
      "password": "angel",
      "profile_image": "a8625093a2e95ee6b5042456b7cccc20.png",
      "device_id": "eVOnz8AMVOs:APA91bHuq9Q4FLcOewUCSAQu79aZNeQsb4710k66g1MHDfZUZWa4ZcARs0SekUfnYUt5sTiKeXfFk_Gg_LdtSKk-pTAaQLxPe9UMkYG9-d-IkDRlGYxkzonQ1h2YN78S7RU0x90NAby_",
      "mobile_no": "9090966666",
      "email_id": "kjfhg@half.com",
      "full_name": "ajjdjd",
      "job_title": "sxsaca",
      "home_address": "scacac",
      "work_phone": "ugiuygitf",
      "work_address": "bbuyiytfi"
    },
  ]}
```

But I want both details in one array. How can I get this?
Can anyone help with this? Thank you..

Comment: side note: it seems you store your passwords as plain text. *don't ever* do that - use `password_hash` to create a hash and `password_verify` to validate it instead.

Comment: will follow your suggestion..Thank you..@FranzGleichmann

Comment: This line is working?? `String number = subObject1.getString("invitee_no");`

Comment: yes for invitation array strings not getting the error only its giving error for user details.@nanocv

Comment: I guess the `response` variable that you are passing to `doPostExecute` method is the result of something like `JSONArray response = json_response.getJSONArray("Invitations");`, isn't it?

Comment: That issue got solved.. Thanks.. :-) @nanocv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are pushing to `$invitations` variable two different associative arrays.
The solution here is to combine the elements of both arrays (array_merge) into only one, and then push it to `$invitation`.

Try to change this code:

```
$invitations[] = $row;
$invitations[] = $result;
```

by this:

```
$invitations[] = array_merge($row, $result);
```

Edit:

To solve the warning `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array` try to force `$result` to array type with a casting:

```
$invitations[] = array_merge($row, (array)$result);
```

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in
<b>/var/www/html/contactsapi/Invitation.php</b> on line.. I am getting the result as expected but getting this warning too.@nanocv

Comment: Well... this sentence `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` is suposed to output an associative array. Any way, you can try to force an array casting. I will edit the answer.

Comment: can you please help me with edited question? @nanocv

Comment: Sure! I can't program in Android but I'll try to help you. Give me a moment for a little research

Answer (score 1):

Use below function as @nanocv told you have to changed as below

```
<?php
   function getInvitations()
{
    $database = new Database(ContactsConstants::DBHOST,ContactsConstants::DBUSER,ContactsConstants::DBPASS,ContactsConstants::DBNAME);
    $dbConnection = $database->getDB();

    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Invitation` WHERE Invitation.invitee_no = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($this-> invitee_no));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $invitations = array();

    if (count($rows) > 0) {

        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("Select * from Users where user_id =?");
            $stmt->execute(array($row['sender_id']));

            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $final_array = array_merge($row,$result);
            $invitations[] = $final_array;
        }

        $response = array("status" => 1, "message" => "Success", "Invitations" => $invitations);
        return json_encode($response);
    }

    else {
        $response = array("status"=>-1,"message"=>"Invitations list is empty");
        return json_encode($response);
    }
}

?>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: <b>Warning</b>: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in <b>/var/www/html/contactsapi/Invitation.php</b> on line.. I am getting the result as expected but getting this warning too.@Albert Akki

Comment: I think '$result' will be object that's why you getting warning. Convert that variable from object to array like '$final_array = array_merge($row,(array)$result);'